# In Database (Agent Properties) what is the difference between <Population> and agent name?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model, I wanted to check the agent parameters in the database, as in the image it is showing two types of agent.

N.B: I have a agent named Order of population 100.

[image]

Comment: when you see population it means that it's an order that is doesn't exist in any population of agents that you have defined... For example when you have a source block that generates agents and you don't define the population explicitely, so they belong in the root agent...